# Keras: Model Always Predicts similar Results

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

So I'm currently working on my first AI/Keras Project in Python, but my NN doens't significantly change the prediction outputs:

```
import keras, numpy, random


# Creating the Model
input = keras.Input(shape=(8,), name="Input")
dense = keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="sigmoid", name="Middle")(input)
select = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="sigmoid", name="Select")(dense)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=select)


def predict(data):
    data = numpy.array([data])
    data = data / 6         # Normalizing

    prediction = model.predict(data)

    for x in prediction:
        print(x)


for _ in range(30):
    data = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(8)]
    predict(data)
```

As you might have already seen, this is only a simplified Version of the whole code (thats why nothing happens with the prediction). I had this problem in the big Model and tried to simplify it, but even like this the Problem still exists.

Here is an example output:

```
[0.45357195 0.5101176  0.6066073  0.59616214 0.32346085]
[0.45234042 0.50832504 0.61470693 0.5896992  0.31719455]
[0.4485785  0.51558554 0.60924697 0.6041078  0.32343972]
[0.43296802 0.4978232  0.60654384 0.5980472  0.32416025]
[0.46071726 0.51882887 0.61999756 0.5960711  0.32239592]
[0.4497589  0.51017994 0.6150334  0.5961156  0.328219  ]
[0.44080874 0.5004228  0.6147976  0.5961118  0.3279655 ]
[0.4618538  0.5148883  0.6156607  0.5945767  0.32228172]
[0.44991705 0.51072496 0.6219714  0.5943718  0.3167036 ]
[0.44801232 0.50875366 0.61004543 0.5957838  0.32481167]
[0.4461697  0.5075315  0.61299646 0.59860665 0.3184844 ]
[0.43305746 0.4930857  0.6096221  0.5926977  0.3309392 ]
[0.44183218 0.5020379  0.61970615 0.5955208  0.3254349 ]
[0.44254482 0.49376535 0.6126899  0.583543   0.32847765]
[0.4403061  0.50721973 0.60946244 0.6034762  0.3315672 ]
[0.4384259  0.5032901  0.60851157 0.5973858  0.32403302]
[0.43846375 0.5022315  0.6135255  0.60117215 0.33535388]
[0.4594089  0.5142279  0.62335753 0.5890998  0.31734776]
[0.43596834 0.49416542 0.6176787  0.5868927  0.32736892]
[0.45383313 0.51128554 0.62625104 0.58994234 0.31612635]
[0.4284321 0.4935397 0.6034159 0.596443  0.3285327]
[0.42604104 0.4915861  0.6057334  0.5972011  0.32937437]
[0.44639084 0.5085275  0.6094539  0.5973595  0.31766823]
[0.45737445 0.51187867 0.61704046 0.5949744  0.32312208]
[0.45286173 0.5039543  0.62771565 0.5865321  0.32633784]
[0.44536707 0.49676734 0.6164142  0.58691347 0.334003  ]
[0.45313308 0.5062818  0.62855715 0.5869772  0.3215919 ]
[0.4594305  0.50981486 0.61838317 0.5850767  0.3186839 ]
[0.44705614 0.50470227 0.62320054 0.5908667  0.32202294]
[0.4542963  0.49835688 0.6314806  0.5773467  0.3272368 ]
```

As you see, the outputs are almost identical, although the input are always random and different.

Why is that?

~Okaghana

Edit: Just for Clarification: I use this Model in an genetic algorithm approach and I need the Outputs to exit a wide variety of values!

Comment: Are you actually training the model somewhere? Why are you using sigmoid activations?

Comment: @JDo I didn't, but as far as i know, it wouldn't make any difference to the final result and would just make the predictions reproducible, so that you would get the same results as me.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Since I'm using the Model in a Genetic Algorithm setup, I neither train it nor have I the Training Data to do so. 
I use Sigmoid-Activation just because its the Activationfunction that I normally see being used and since I'm not an expert, I just take what everyone else does.

Comment: @Okaghana Sigmoid is not the most used activation since the 2010's, prefer ReLU.

Comment: Ok. So I tried to swap the activation function of either one or both of the Layers with another one, like tanh, linear, relu, etc..   The Output indeed got more diverse and more distributed (apparently the sigmoid flattened the values a bit), but still not as much as I like them to be. I don't think that the choice of the activation function is the major problem here!

Comment: Without seeing how the layers are trained it is hard to find the problem. Could we get to see the training curves?

Are the inputs normalized?

Comment: @IgnacioPeletier I don't train the model. Yes the inputs are normalized.